# Defining unique constraint creating a USI

Tags: teradata

i have  a requirement where i need to enforce uniqueness on a column. However, when i define a unique constraint teradata automatically defines a USI on this column. I don't want this to happen. How can i enforce uniqueness without creating a USI.

```
create table cfdw2_samods_stg.STORE_DIM_968
(
store_id integer ,
store_name varchar(100)  not null,
store varchar(100)  not null,

CONSTRAINT STORE_DIM_968_pk unique ( store_name ),
CONSTRAINT STORE_DIM_968_dpk unique ( store )
) unique primary index(store_id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teradata automatically enforces the UNIQUE constraint applied to a column as a USI. As a bonus, a USI provides a 2-AMP operation when accessing the table via the USI.

**EDIT**
There is overhead for the USI subtable maintenance - additional IO operation. The CPU overhead isn't terrible. Hard RI in Teradata is another option but then you have the overhead of maintaining the RI reference.

You can use DBQL to measure the actual cost of maintaining the USI subtable in terms of CPU and IO by loading the table with and without the UNIQUE constraint. I have seen tables with 10's of billions of rows enforce uniqueness via a USI without a significant overhead placed on the ETL.

Lastly, you can enforce the uniqueness of the column in your ETL code and make sure you don't insert duplicate values.

Comment: But, The inserts get affected right? Any workaround for this?

Comment: The sole purpose of that constraint is to enforce uniqueness. I am not using that column in any of the queries or even the table is not accessed via that column.

Comment: Thanks, a lot for your response Rob. I was looking for hard RI on how can this enforce uniqueness.